# Web scrape the text which is not in the quotation marks of HTML

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the information that is not in the quotation marks using Python. For example,

```
nummber = page_soup.findAll("span", {"id": "referenznummer"})
nummber

# result
[<span id="referenznummer">Referenznummer:<span class="ng-binding"> 12150-S</span></span>]

location = page_soup.findAll("li", {"id": "arbeitsort"})
location

# result
[<li class="ba-icon-location" id="arbeitsort">Koblenz am Rhein</li>]
```

**12150-S** and **Koblenz am Rhein** are actually the information I would like to scrape. But they are not in the quotation marks, so I do not know how to locate them. Unfortunately, I did not find any solutions on the website. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mind sharing the url to the webstie you're scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for you Derek.

```
nummber = page_soup.findAll("span", {"id": "referenznummer"})
for data in nummber: 
    print(str(data.get_text()))

location = page_soup.findAll("li", {"id": "arbeitsort"})
for data in location:
    print(str(data.get_text()))
```

If you want to make list of directories then you do like this:

```
details = []
nummber = page_soup.findAll("span", {"id": "referenznummer"})
location = page_soup.findAll("li", {"id": "arbeitsort"})
for dataid,dataloc in zip(nummber,location):
   d[dataid.get_text()] = dataloc.get_text()
   details.append(d)
```